# 80's(?) time travel trilogy with a one-armed war veteran dragged to the future with World War III and telepath wars

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, books

The main character was a war veteran who had lost an arm and used a sword to strengthen his other arm.  He is caught in a time probe from the far future and accidentally dragged forward (in the first book).  This future has already had WWIII and a couple of telepath wars.

He meets and falls in love with one of the scientists' daughters (there are two). The future people produce or clone a new arm and hand for our main character. I think there are war concerns, as I remember there being "eternal" highways that were indestructable and being used by both sides to mobilize. I don't remember all the plot twists.

I think there were three books, but it may have been four. I'm pretty sure I first read this back in the early 80's.

Comment: I think I know the series, though I can't for the life of me find the details now. I read them in the early 1990s - there was a chap from the present day taken into the future by a country that had just discovered time travel, shortly before being invaded, and they were using time travel to go back in time and slow the invasion down. Does that sound at all familiar?

Answer (score 9):

It could be "With Fate Conspire" by Mike Shupp,  its the first book of the "Destiny Makers" series. There's 5 books in total, it's been a long time since I read them but what you've described sounds familiar.

From [FantasticFiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/s/mike-shupp/):

> Vietnam veteran and MIT student Tim Harper uses his new invention, a time machine, to travel ninety thousand years into the future, where he is captured by Alghera clansmen who seek to use his discovery to change the course of history.

1. *With Fate Conspire* (1985)
2. *Morning of Creation* (1986)
3. *Soldier of Another Fortune* (1988)
4. *Death's Gray Land* (1991)
5. *The Last Reckoning* (1991)

Comment: I don't know if that's the book the OP was thinking of; but it's definitely the one I thought of. Thanks for the details - to the library!

Comment: '"eternal" highways that were indestructable and being used by both sides to mobilize' - that sounds like Death's Gray Land. I don't have my copy anymore, but Clive Warner's review on Goodreads is a good indication that this is a match.