# Time Travel Series 60-70s 3-4 books - Time machine appears on the lawn at a university

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Trying to find an old series, cannot find anything by Googling front covers for time-travel novels.

Main character gets in a time machine and goes forward, watching the rise and fall of at least 2 more civilizations (ours blew up shortly into novel). Decides to help a civilization on the future east coast of the USA but eventually, through multiple novels, and the other side getting a machine, it turns into a giant time war.

Comment: It's a little later than the 70s, but this does remind me of the answer to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23198/cant-remember-time-travel-trilogy-name

Answer (score -1):

Vernor Vinge uses stasis fields for one way time travel to future. Some involve a war. Anarchists seem to have taken over early. (Re: Aztlan vs Republic of New Mexico water wars?)

Comment: So, what's the title?

Comment: Vernor Vinge wrote "The Peace War", "The Ungoverned", and "Marooned In Real Time". I particularly recommend reading "Marooned In Real Time". Vinge once told me that he thought it was the best thing he ever wrote. Of course, he's written a lot more since then; it may not be true now.

Comment: Those are _great books_ but are _certainly not_ the answer to this question.